# How to add defines to moc via cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I have a header like this:

```
#ifdef WITH_QT
#include <QObject>
#endif

namespace foo {
#ifdef WITH_QT
    Q_NAMESPACE
#endif

    enum class Letters {A, B, C };
#ifdef WITH_QT
    Q_ENUM_NS(Letters)
#endif
}
```

And a cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core)
qt5_wrap_cpp(moc_source foo.h)

add_library(foo STATIC ${moc_source})
target_compile_definitions(foo PUBLIC WITH_QT)
```

`make VERBOSE=1` shows (abbreviated):

```
/usr/bin/moc foo.h
foo.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moc` needs to be run with

```
/usr/bin/moc -DWITH_QT foo.h
```

CMake isn't forwarding your compile definitions to `moc`.  That prevents those macros from existing, and inhibits `moc` from finding anything useful to generate.

A few solutions:

1. This will add `WITH_QT` globally:

```
add_definitions(-DWITH_QT)
```

2. This more refined method will tell `qt5_wrap_cpp` to import the compile definitions of a specific target.  This is better as it avoids contaminating the compile definitions of the rest of your project.

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(moc_source foo.h TARGET foo)
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-cmake-qt5-wrap-cpp.html for `qt5_wrap_cpp()` usage.

3. Use [`AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#automoc) by changing your CMakeLists to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_library(foo STATIC foo.h)
target_compile_definitions(foo PUBLIC WITH_QT)
```

All three solutions will give you an archive with the missing symbol:

```
$ nm -gC libfoo.a 

moc_foo.cpp.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U qt_version_tag
0000000000000000 D foo::staticMetaObject
```